# Android Javascript app slower than the same in-browser

Tags: android, webkit

I wrapped a JavaScript app that prints 200 text messages on the screen into an Android app using WebView. The exact same app executes in the native Android browser about 2x faster than the installed app. Why is that, and is there a way to speed it up as an installed app? The Android version is 2.3.3 and the device is Motorola Droid 3.

Answer (score 0):

WebView capabilities are limited as compared to Browser capabilities. One of the most important thing to improve performance would be to reduce the size of your js file (all static files) as from my experience loading takes more time.